# google-chrome: making the start page be an extension (not an app)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there any way to start up the google-chrome browser so that an extension (not an app) gets launched as its start page?

I know I can do the following, but it only works if `app-id` refers to an installed app, not an installed extension ...

```
chrome --app-id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

If the specified `app-id` is the ID of an installed extension (not an app), then chrome doesn't launch it.

Is it even possible to launch an extension as chrome's start page?

Thank you in advance.

CORRECTION: I am referring to the start page, and I have clarified the wording of this question accordingly.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "home page"? The page that opens when you click the home button in the toolbar? If so, you can set the home URL in Chrome's settings: enable the home button, and enter a full chrome-extension:// URL of an html file inside the extension.

Comment: I mean the start page.  But when I give the full chrome-extension:// url on the chome command line, all that pops up is the "chome-extensions://" page with entries for all my installed extensions, including the one I'm requesting. The extension itself does not get invoked.

Comment: Actually, I got this to work. See my latest `Answer`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it, with the help of wOxxOm ...

```
chrome chome-extension://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/index.html
```

This works for all extensions that have some sort of HTML page for their startup. For the extension I'm dealing with, this is `index.html`, but different extensions might have different HTML startup pages.

I see now that the URL with the reference to the HTML file is simply the extension ID followed by a slash, followied by the HTML file name. I was previously trying it incorrectly with the extension's version number as part of the path.

And to be clear, some extensions do not have HTML startup pages, and they therefore cannot be invoked in this manner.